# php telegram bot send photo don't run

Tags: php, json, api, telegram-bot

I try to made a telegram bot, but I've a problem when I send a photo.
This is my code:

I have this function:

```
function apiRequestImage($method, $parameters)
{

  if (!is_string($method)) {
    error_log("Method name must be a string\n");
    return false;
  }

  if (!$parameters) {
    $parameters = array();
  } else if (!is_array($parameters)) {
    error_log("Parameters must be an array\n");
    return false;
  }

  foreach ($parameters as $key => &$val) {
    // encoding to JSON array parameters, for example reply_markup
    if (!is_numeric($val) && !is_string($val)) {
      $val = json_encode($val);
    }
  }

  $urlpath = API_URL.$method.'?'.http_build_query($parameters);


  $handle = curl_init($urlpath);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
}
```

and this to call it

```
function processMessage($message) {
  // process incoming message
  $message_id = $message['message_id'];
  $chat_id = $message['chat']['id'];
  $img = curl_file_create('test.png','image/png');
  if (isset($message['text'])) {
    // incoming text message
    $text = $message['text'];

    if (strpos($text, "/start") === 0) {
      apiRequestJson("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Hello', 'reply_markup' => array(
        'keyboard' => array(array('Hello', 'Hi','Bye')),
        'one_time_keyboard' => true,
        'resize_keyboard' => true)));
    } else if ($text === "Hello" || $text === "Hi") {
      apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'Nice to meet you'));
    } else if ($text === "Bye") {
      apiRequestImage("sendPhoto", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'photo' => '@'.$img));
    }else if (strpos($text, "/stop") === 0) {
      // stop now
    } else {
      apiRequestWebhook("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "reply_to_message_id" => $message_id, "text" => 'Cool'));
    }
  } else {
    apiRequest("sendMessage", array('chat_id' => $chat_id, "text" => 'I understand only text messages'));
  }
}
```

and call all

```
if (isset($update["message"])) {
  processMessage($update["message"]);
}
```

The text run, but the photo no.
Can you help me?

The rest of code: http://pastebin.com/BKPxe2KC

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple parts. I recommend that test part by part, 
For example, your `function` has `keyboard` part and it seems not working(bad Telegram syntax), and it can prevent other parts(like photo sending). In my opinion it is better you first work on just on thing(for example sending photo) and when it did its job best then go on and add keyboard.(This is a working keyboard code https://stackoverflow.com/a/37948952/6478645.