# Telegram bot keybord send via JSON

Tags: json, telegram-bot, botframework

I'm using MS Bot Framework. I want to sen custom keyboard to user, so i try to reply message with this JSON:

```
        public async Task<Message> Post([FromBody]Message message)
    {

        var connector = new ConnectorClient();

        if (message.Type == "Message")
        {             
            var replyMessage = message.CreateReplyMessage($"You sent message");

            replyMessage.ChannelData = @"
```

{
    ""method"": ""sendMessage"",
    ""parameters"":
    {
        ""reply_markup"":
        {
            ""keyboard"":[[[""1""],[""2""]],[[""3""]],[[""4""],[""5""],[""6""]]]
        }
    }
}";

```
            return replyMessage;



        }
        else
        {
            return HandleSystemMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

But nothing happens. For example, this message with sticker works fine:

```
replyMessage.ChannelData = @"
{
    ""method"": ""sendSticker"",
    ""parameters"":
    {
        ""sticker"":
        {
            ""url"": ""https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/LittleCarron.gif"",
            ""mediaType"": ""image/gif""
        }
    }
}";
```

I think that the problem is in "keyboard" part, somewhere in array.

Answer (score 0):

Add another bracket to your `keyboard`.( one more array) like this:

```
""keyboard"":[[[""1""],[""2""]],[[""3""]],[[""4""],[""5""],[""6""]]]
```

know there is triple array inside each other instead of two of your code.

[Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)

a part of working code:

```
    $keyboard = [
    'keyboard' =>
        [[['text' => '1'], ['text' => '2']], [['text' => '3']], [['text' => '4'], ['text' => '5'], ['text' => '6']]],
    'one_time_keyboard' => true,
];
$markup = json_encode($keyboard, true);
$data = [
    'chat_id' => sender_user_id($update),
    'text' => 'JUST A TEXT',
    'reply_markup' => $markup];


$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . BOT_TOKEN . '/SendMessage';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, still, no keyboard recieved.

Comment: due to this documentation [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), `chat_id` and `text` parameters are required,if your second code is working so you didn't enter any `text` parameter and it MUST not be empty string! Also I updated my answer and I add a working code with php.

Comment: You are working with Telegram not via MS Bot Framework, just using Telegram API. I try to send message via this framework. And when i execute "sendSticker" it works fine (chat_id also required here, but i dont set it). I think, that chat_id and other stuff are already set in "CreateReplyMessage" method.

Comment: I added full code of not-working method, but something wrong with code highliting.

Comment: I know, but look again to my nesting brackets. I mistyped them, and now i correct them. In each array( open close bracket) there Must be only one keyboard element. and telegram bot is very new and not complete framework is there,so maybe in some parts its better to use crude coding. certainly its just only my opinion and everybody do its best . but in this problem we can find the problem sooner if you give some code feedback that you recive from telegram server after each message sending.

Comment: Unfortunatelly i can't see code feedback from Teletgram server, because my bot is hosted on Microsoft Azure cloud, so i cant see anything coming in.

Comment: you can send Telegram reply(feedback) to your chat_id

Comment: Can you tell me little bit more about how to do this?

Comment: you can send the response(feedback) as a string to your id, BUT i recommend a more better way for you. Host your codes locally and use `ngrok` program as interface. `ngrok` supply a https interface very very simple( as simple as pressing clicks) , then it gives you an online page and shows all responses from Telegram

Comment: Thank youl. I send keyboard as you suggested: ""keyboard"":[[[""1""],[""2""]],[[""3""]],[[""4""],[""5""],[""6""]]]. And i added to my message text  ChannelData.ToString(). So i see Json, that i send to Telegram: 

{ "method": "sendMessage", "parameters": { "reply_markup": { "keyboard":[["1","2"],["3"],["4","5","6"]] } } }

Looks like it is correct, but still no effect.

Comment: Telegram should send something like this `{"ok":true,"result":{`.... When it says `false` instead of true, that means Telegram's wont understand it and you should correct it.This is my code result from Telegram: `{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":203,"from":{"id":YYYYYYYYY,"first_name":"My Bot Name","username":"myBot"},"chat":{"id":XXXXXXXXX,"first_name":"MyFirstName","last_name":"MyLastName","type":"private"},"date":1466745019,"text":"JUST A TEXT"}}`   XXX & YYY are numbers.